# Symbolic evaluation expressions containing a user-defined function

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

I have a function

```
F[r] = (-1)^(r + 1) Binomial[n, r]/r
```

I would like to evaluate `F[x+1]/F[x]` for some arbitrary `x` (that is not defined already) and simplify it. How can I get Mathematica to do this for me? I am looking for a method that will allow me to do this easily with different variable choices and more complex expressions than the ratio; that is, I am not looking for a method that involves copying and pasting the function definition.

Putting the function definition followed by `F[x+1]/F[x]` into the code outputs the ratio straight back.

#### Edit

`FunctionExpand` seems to do something very similar, but does not seem to work for user defined functions.

Comment: Your definition of `F` does not include a pattern so it literally only works for an input of `r`. `F[r_] = (-1)^(r + 1)*Binomial[n, r]/r; F[x + 1]/F[x] // FunctionExpand // Simplify`

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn the syntax for defining functions. For your example it would be:

```
F[r_] := (-1)^(r + 1) Binomial[n, r]/r
```

and then

```
F[x + 1]/F[x]
```

gives

[image: result]

and

```
FullSimplify[%]
```

gives

[image: result]

Suggest you follow [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html) for a tutorial on this subject.